# Can I write a general wrapper class which adds a function to any class?

Tags: python, class, wrapper

So there is an encoder library with many different encoder classes in Machine Learning:

```
from category_encoders import BinaryEncoder as BE, OneHotEncoder as OE
```

These classes miss some functionality, I want to add a function called `get_feature_names_out()` - what it does is not important.

My approach is to create a class like this:

```
class BinaryEncoder(BE):
    def get_feature_names_out():
        # do stuff and return value

encoder = BinaryEncoder()
```

This works fine, but I do not want to write a wrapper class for every single encoder. Is it possible to replace `BE` in the class definition with a general object? So that I can create an instance like this:

```
encoder = GeneralEncoderClass(BinaryEncoder())
```

I can not figure out how I can let the `GeneralEncoderClass` inherit all the functionality of its "parent" encoder class, without defining it in the the header.

Comment: Look up class decorators; they can modify a class after definition time exactly the way you want (either with decorator `@` syntax or just be calling them on the class) without relying on inheritance at all.

Comment: Do the encoders share a common base class? You could patch that class, then all the children would inherit the new method.

Comment: You don't need to create a wrapper class because you can do it with a class decorator *function*, which is described in the documentation in the [Class definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) section (see **classdef**) — they are *very* similar to [function decorators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions).

Comment: Can you? Sure. Should you? No, you're subclassing classes that were never intended to be used that way and you're going to create a very brittle interface. Python doesn't have extension methods, so just write a standalone `def get_feature_names_out(arg)` at the toplevel and call it as a function.

Comment: If  I use a decorater I still have to decorate every single class to use the function?